# angularjs how to find img element height and width

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Hi I'm trying to find an image element's height and width in order to resize it.  However everytime I use elem.height() or elem.width() I get 0?

html

```
<div>
    <img data-ng-src="{{photosrc}}" lightbox-resize-image>
</div>
```

directive.js

```
.directive('lightboxResizeImage', function() {
return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {

        console.log(elem.parent().width()); //==equals 575
        console.log(elem.width()); //this always equals 0

  }
  });
```

Comment: Ensure that the image is loaded first.

Comment: `elem.on('load', function(){console.log($(this).width())})`

Comment: i'd suggest only doing the above after ensuring that it doesn't have a width already. a cached image may have already triggered that event.

Answer (score 2):

See code below:

```
.directive('lightboxResizeImage', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
             console.log(elem.parent().width()); // =575
             console.log(elem[0].offsetHeight);
        }
    }
});
```